# All browsers are displaying junk text.how to get the web page without junk?

Tags: 16.04, firefox, google-chrome, fonts

i tried by installing  **msttcorefonts** but there is no use.All three browsers chrome,firefox,chromium displaying junk text.

[image]

**edit1:-**

i followed the below steps.

1. `sudo apt-get install msttcorefonts`
2. `sudo fc-cache -fv`

Comment: How did you install `msttcorefonts`? Could you add this information to your question?

Comment: You've gone to what appears to be a Google international web site, and it's trying to display other choice (languages) in their native font, some of which you don't have installed. Either install the missing fonts, or use google.com.

Comment: ps: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/ttf-mscorefonts-installer_3.4+nmu1ubuntu2_all.deb

Comment: The image is the Google India home page.  The `msttcorefonts` package has limited support for non-European language characters.  You need to find and install fonts for languages on that page (likely Hindi, Arabic, Pashtun, etc.).  Until you have the needed fonts, you'll get placeholder characters for those languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the URL you showed us (https://www.google.co.in), try to install some Indic fonts:

```
sudo apt install fonts-indic
```